# Coldfusion site - Chrome tries to link to https version of files that don't exist

Tags: google-chrome, coldfusion

A couple coldfusion-based sites we run are having a problem in Chrome.

I'm using `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<cfoutput>#request.rootPath#</cfoutput>_data/styles/website.css">` to refer to the stylesheet. When I go to the site using Chrome, the stylesheet doesn't load, and when I look in the source, the link is pointing to an `https` url instead of `http`.

Somehow, it thinks the stylesheet link should start with `https`, even when the site is just regular-ol' `http`.

http://www.preston-hanley.com/
and
http://www.fmchosp.com/

It seems to be returning `https` any time I use `<cfoutput>#request.rootPath#</cfoutput>`...

Any idea why that would be and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Search through your code base and see where is `request.rootPath` defined, since I don't think it is something defined by ColdFusion.  Most likely it is deduced from the `cgi` scope and I saw [Dave Quested](https://twitter.com/davequested/) tweeted yesterday that the latest chrome reports something different for `cgi.https`.

Quote from: https://twitter.com/davequested/status/623968823276761089

> Chrome 44.0.2403.89 appears to change cgi.https behaviour in
>   #coldfusion, now seeing https = 1, not https = off.

[His workaround](https://twitter.com/davequested/status/623981931508576256) is to use `CGI.server_port EQ 443` instead.

This is the [Chrome bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=501842)  according to [Brad Wood](https://cfml.slack.com/archives/cfml-general/p1437583848001441) on [#CFML Slack](https://cfml.slack.com/archives/cfml-general/links)

Comment: That fixed it. Thank you!